# Changing f.select to checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have the following in my view at which the can select several categories:

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
    Categories <br>
    <%= f.select :category_ids, Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %><br>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I want the user to be selecting the categories with checkboxes instead of drop down list.

I am not sure how this is possible. Two parts: 1. How it will display several checkboxes and 2. How it will be saving the user's selections as it is saving fine for the f.select above.

The approach (which is not complete) that I though of is to iterate through the categories and add a checkbox for each category. However I am not sure if this will make sure that the several selections will be saved.

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <%= category.name %><br>
    <%= f.check_box  :category_ids %>
```

Any guidance/tip to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [***collection_check_boxes***](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, :multiple => true %><br>
```